# syntax error near unexpected token `do' in bash script

Tags: bash, unix, ffmpeg

I have bash script which takes 3 parameters from the command line. It compares all of the files in the directory to see if they are of the type of the first 2 parameters. If they are, the script converts such files to the type of the third parameter using an FFMPEG command. I would execute the script with the following command:

```
./convert.sh .avi .mp4 .flv
```

That this, this script would convert all of the .avi and .mp4 files to .flv.

When I run the script, I get the error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `do' in bash script.
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the first parameter passed
# $2 is the second parameter passed 
# $3 is the third parameter passed

for file in *.*; 
    do 
        #comparing the file types in the directory to the first 2 parameters passed
        if[  ( ${file: -4} == "$1" ) || ( ${file: -4 } == "$2" )  ]{
            export extension=${file: -4}
            #converting such files to the type of the first parameter using the FFMPEG comand
            do ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.extension}"$3;
done
```

Comment: Test your code with [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: I did but I am a beginner in bash. I don't understand some of the error messages well on shellcheck. Any hint of where I went wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, i can see only the shebang line is correct in this script :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your formatting and syntax.  sjsam's advice to use shellcheck is good, but the short version is that you should be using square brackets instead of round ones on the internal brackets of your if statement:

```
if [ ${file: -4} == "$1" ] || [ ${file: -4 } == "$2" ] {
```

And I don't think you need the 'do' before your ffmpeg line or the curly bracket at the end of the line above, so you end up with...

```
for file in *.*; 
    do 
    #comparing the file types in the directory to the first 2 parameters passed
    if [  ${file: -4} == "$1" ] || [ ${file: -4 } == "$2" ]
        export extension=${file: -4}
        #converting such files to the type of the first parameter using the FFMPEG comand
        ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.extension}"$3;
    fi
done
```

Comment: Glad to hear it, although Gordon's answer below is much more thorough than mine - I corrected the 'if[' missing space, but forgot to mention it, and neglected to spot the missing 'then' also...

Answer (score 9):

For me, it was due to `CRLF`. It should be `LF` for linux env.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of syntax errors here. Let's start with the line:

```
if[  ( ${file: -4} == "$1" ) || ( ${file: -4 } == "$2" )  ]{
```

- You need a space between `if` and `[` (or whatever comes after it). As written, the shell is treating "if[" as the name of a command, which isn't what you want at all.
- The `[ ... ]` style of conditional doesn't understand `||` (it uses `-o` instead), requires that all shell metacharacters (like parentheses) be escaped or quoted, might not understand `==` (just `=` is the standard), and will get very confused if any of the unquoted variable/parameter references are blank.
- `if` conditionals end with `then` (either on the next line, or after a `;`) not `{`

You could fix it like this:

```
if [  \( "${file: -4}" = "$1" \) -o \( "${file: -4}" = "$2" \) ]; then
```

Or, since you're using `bash` (instead of a more basic shell), you can use the `[[ ... ]]` conditional style, which has much cleaner syntax:

```
if [[ "${file: -4}" = "$1" || "${file: -4}" = "$2" ]]; then
```

Next, remove the `do` before `ffmpeg`. `do` is part of the syntax for `for` and `while` loops; you already have one above (where it belongs), and this one just doesn't make sense. This is what's causing the error you see.

Next, the way you're replacing the file's extension won't work right. The variable reference `"${file%.extension}"$3` will try to remove ".extension" (not the variable, just the string) from the end of `$file`. It also has `$3` outside the quotes, which can cause trouble. You could fix it by using `"${file%$extension}$3"` instead, but frankly I'd just use `"${file%.*}$3"` to remove the extension no matter what length it is (and I'd also redo the `if` comparisons similarly, but that's more complicated).

Finally, you need a `fi` (after the `ffmpeg` line) to end the conditional. Every `if` needs a `then` and a `fi`.

And just as a stylistic thing, you don't need `;` at the end of a line in shell; it's only needed when you're putting multiple commands (or things like `do` and `then`) on the same line. Anyway, here's my quick rewrite:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the first parameter passed
# $2 is the second parameter passed 
# $3 is the third parameter passed

for file in *.*; do
    #comparing the file types in the directory to the first 2 parameters passed
    if [[  "${file: -4}" = "$1" || "${file: -4}" = "$2"  ]]; then
        #converting such files to the type of the first parameter using the FFMPEG comand
        ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.*}$3"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Even I got stuck with the same error.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsWGF.png]  --> this link will take you to the error message.

The code which made me encounter this message is provided in the link below. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wom7q.png]

If you observe the error related to **do** command is followed by an error about the syntax of the while. You can get rid of the error just by introducing spaces around the square brackets.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1C7x.png]

This is due to the fact that the **[** is not a **shell-built-in** rather it receives the expression as arguments. If **[** is not surrounded by spaces the interpreter interprets it as $PATH.

I hope this answer helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Please don't post error messages and code as images (and if you do use images, the [formatting guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) will help you do so correctly). Code should always be added to questions and the answers as text. Images cannot be searched, and they are not accessible to people using assistive technology.

Answer (score 0):

Your script could be reduced to simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
    [[ ${file: -4} = $1 || ${file: -4} = $2 ]] && ffmpeg -i "$file" "${file%.*}$3"
done
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted by mistake, can you edit it so I can upvote again?