# Shell script to loop through and execute sql files in a directory

Tags: oracle, shell

I am quite new to shell scripting and trying to create a shell script which goes into a directory and picks the *.sql files in the folder and executes the identified files.

I know that it is possible to call the sql files from within the shell script but I want to separate the SQL files from the shell script itself as the number of scripts are quite much and it will be easier to maintain outside the shell itself.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and how it didn't work? That would also make your goal more clear. How do you "call the sql files"?

Comment: Please do not reinvent wheel, just use **[Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)** You will get much more, script execution, once or every time, table with status, all-at-once per script and so on.

Comment: I removed  the `sql` tag as the question has got nothing to do with SQL language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a temporary shell script dynamically by including all the *.sql filenames to be executed. Then run this shell script at the end.

```
cd your_sql_script_path  

final_script="/your_script_path/final_script.sh"

echo "sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
CONNECT user/password;

whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
set echo off 
set heading off" > ${final_script}

for sql_file in *.sql;
do
  echo "@${sql_file}" >>${final_script}
done

echo -e "exit;\nEOF" >>${final_script}


chmod +x ${final_script}

sh ${final_script}
```

Comment: Thanks Kaushik, your solution pretty much sums what I am trying to achieve. But when i run this, I receive an error within the do loop "syntax error near unexpected token 'do"

Comment: it does not seem to iterate through the for loop and the sql files are not written into the dynamic shell being generated.  Syntax error unexpected token 'do error received.

Comment: @Flow7 : This syntax is correct and works in bash. I think you have made a mistake while editing. Check it correctly. May be you need to convert it to unix format,  you have some control m characters while copying or you could be using different shell  etc. Refer https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390497/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do/390498 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151619/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do-in-bash-script

Comment: @Flow7 : Also note that you may use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to check for syntax errors. It is a very helpful tool.  You may check this code as well. I have modified slightly the echo statement and placed a semicolon in the for statement, although it was syntactically correct otherwise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick responses and help. @Kaushik Nayak, this now works as intended. It was needing a dos2unix conversion. Appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$ for i in *.sql; 
do 
    echo "$i and do your stuff"; 
done
```

output:

```
script01.sql and do your stuff
script02.sql and do your stuff
```